# NO gesture recognizer uiimageview in ui scrollview

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to create a slider of UIImage, with possibility of zoom in the image and swipe to an other image.
My swipe is not recognized, and i don't know why.
I use cocoa pods, if you know a pod who do this, please, tell me.
Or, is it a possibility to use the code of the iphone, in photo gallery?

This is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];


    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"********************/test.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSArray *responseObject) {
        //NSLog(@"URL");
        //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);


        urlArray = responseObject;

        //NSLog(@" %@", urlArray);
        int i=0;

        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlArray objectAtIndex:i]];

        //NSLog(@"%@", url);
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];



    [self.view setBackgroundColor:RGB(32,32,32)];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
        self.scrollView = scrollView;


    if (img.size.width>img.size.height){
    //format d'images paysage
        NSLog(@"PORTAIT image paysage");

        NSLog(@"%f", img.size.width);
        NSLog(@"%f", img.size.height);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width+img.size.height, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        //imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
       imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
        self.imgView = imageView;
        [self.imgView setImage:img];


    }

    if (img.size.height>img.size.width && orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
        //format d'images portrait
        NSLog(@"PORTAIT image portrait");
        NSLog(@"%f", img.size.width);
        NSLog(@"%f", img.size.height);
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,  img.size.height-img.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        //imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
        self.scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
        self.imgView = imageView;

    }


        if (img.size.height==img.size.width){
            //format d'images portrait
            NSLog(@"ICI %f", img.size.width);
            NSLog(@"%f", img.size.height);
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)];
            //imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
            self.scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
            self.imgView = imageView;

            [self.imgView setImage:img];

        }

    }


    } failure:nil];
}


- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft) {
        NSLog(@"Left Swipe");
    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight) {
        NSLog(@"Right Swipe");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`s are not being triggered because the UIImageView you have attached them to is inside of a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` will be capturing the gestures before the UIImageView gets them.

The best way to do what you are proposing is to put the `UIImageView` inside of it's own `UIScrollView` for zooming, like you have done, and then put each of the `UIScrollView`'s in a larger `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled`. Obviously you will have to do some basic frame calculation to position the `UIScrollView`'s inside of the top `UIScrollView` and set it's contentSize.

You could always use a `UIPageViewController` which is probably what I would do.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Is it possible to use UiPageViewController with zoom ?
I try to put my scrollView1 in an other scrollViewTop, and add swipe gesture on scrollViewTop, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Don't add a swipe gesture... It's a scroll view. It will scroll.